# Can't convert the Java Encog 3.3 XOR NEAT example to use use HyperNEAT

Tags: java, encog, neat

I am trying to convert the Encog XOR using NEAT example to use HyperNEAT instead.

I have spent many hours trying to figure out how to do it and reading a lot of Encog documentation and about NEAT and HyperNEAT in general but I can't figure out how to do it.

The best I can think of is switching the line 
`NEATNetwork network = (NEATNetwork)train.getCODEC().decode(train.getBestGenome());`
 with 
`NEATNetwork network = (NEATNetwork) new HyperNEATCODEC().decode(train.getBestGenome());`
but then I simply get a `NullPointerException`.

I am not if I am missing something small or gravely misunderstanding some concept here.

Any help and/or example code would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Java Encog 3.3